# Flex Footer won't stay at bottom in Chrome

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to get my footer to stay at the bottom, only when the content is shorter than the viewport. If it is taller, the footer should stay below the content, so that you have to scroll to see it.

This works correctly in Firefox and Edge, but not in Chrome or IE.

In Chrome, as you'll see, making the viewport shorter than the content leaves the footer "stuck" to the bottom of the view port. If you then scroll, you'll see the footer scroll up the page.

I believe the issue is in the contentContainer:

```css
#contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This div holds the content and the footer, so that it can have the scroll bar instead of the content itself. I'm not really sure what's wrong with it, though.

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#app,
#appContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#header {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
#footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="appContainer">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="contentContainer">
      <div id="content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om7veLpL/).

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way, hope this is what are you looking for

https://jsfiddle.net/wzz703da/

```
html, body, #app
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#app, #appContainer
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#header
{
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#contentContainer
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

#footer
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I needed. It may help the next person who comes along if you post what exactly you changed. It took me a bit to see it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I just found out this doesn't quite do what I'd like. In my example, My header is static and does not scroll out of view, but this code doesn't do that.

Comment: @Troncoso you mean in your example header is fixed ? static is default position in css.
Why simply don't apply `position: fixed` to header ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changing the properties contentContainer from width to min-width, and content - flex-shrink to 0:

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#app,
#appContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#header {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 36px);
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
#footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="appContainer">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="contentContainer">
      <div id="content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```