# Collapsing Flexbox mystery

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a website consisting of 3 block-level siblings: a header, div `site-content`, and footer.

I have my `body`tag set to be a flexbox as so:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
```

The center `site-content` div is `flex-grow: 1`.

This is working fine, and gives me this layout (the dashed box is to simulate what shows on the visible area of the screen. The page scrolls as it should).

[image]

My problem arises since I want to add a vertically/horizontally centered box in this `site-content` div on some pages.  So, I create a `div` for this box and set the  `site content` to this:

```
  .site-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

And then the `site-content` div immediately collapses to this:

[image]

The footer rides up instead of staying at the bottom. What the heck?

What make it more frustrating is that a [simple codepen reconstruction](https://codepen.io/smlombardi/live/amPEGv) works fine... so I am having trouble isolating the cause of this issue.

Comment: It works the way you want in Firefox and Edge, but not in Chrome.

Comment: This may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40093739/3597276

Comment: Can you add simple jsfiddle for example?

Comment: I have a link to a codepen in there

Answer (score 0):

If you're giving `display: flex` to the `body` element you also could include `html` like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/nrwa33ry/2/

```
body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, no not really.  The display: flex only affects its children.  `html` has only one child, `body`.  So applying `height:100%` to the `html` tag is required, but not the rest.  See https://jsfiddle.net/1nnqqmeo/

Comment: Edited my answer, that's why its better providing your fiddle.